# How to remove some options in visual editor?

Tags: visual-editor

I want remove some options in visual editor.
How to remove them?

For example i want to remove the following.

1. Align left option
2. Align center option
3. Align right option
4. More tag option
5. Add media
6. Toggle fullscreen
7. Toggle spellchecker
8. Show/hide kitchen sink
9. strikethrough

Please help me to remove them from my wordpress visual editor. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this plugin. It allows you to add/remove buttons on the visual editor -> http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/